# Print string from db with ruby code in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I have variables:

```
@variable_2 = "test data"
@variable_1 =  Model.description(eg: "print in view : #{@variable_2}")
```

I want to get this output:

```
'print in view : test_data'
```

I am doing like this in erb file:

```
<%= @variable_1 %>
```

and the result is:

```
'print in view : #{@variable_2}'
```

What format should I use?

Comment: You need to assign `@variable_2` first in order to use that in `@variable_1`.

Comment: Like that only i am doing.

Comment: Use double quotes when you need to interpolate `"#{variable}"`

Comment: What is the exact exact value of `@variable_1` that comes from the db. Your sample data which you have provided works fine with double quotes *("")*

Comment: @variable_1 can be any string value which we fetch from db. in some cases it is 'print in view : #{@variable_2}' in that case variable_2's value test_data this has to be displayed. Am i clear? Sample data is hard coded. Try fetching from db.

Comment: @shahanahamza unfortunately not.

Comment: Updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is single quotes as it will not execute interpolation. Try changing it to double quotes:

```
"print in view : #{@variable_2}"
```

Comment: I didn't give variable_1 manually. it comes from db. eg: variable_1 = Model.first.description.

Comment: Try this then "print in view : #{Model.first.description}"

Comment: variable_1 = Model.first.description = "print in view :  #{@variable_2}". The message can vary.

Comment: Sorry Am unable to get you.
Can you tell me exactly what are you trying to do

Comment: i have updated the question. Can you please check that?

Comment: Try variable_1 = Model.description.to_s

Answer (score 0):

You should use double quotes for string interpolation.

Change it to:

```
@variable_1 = "print in view : #{@variable_2.description}"
```

Comment: I didn't give variable_1 manually. it comes from db. eg: variable_1 = Model.first.description.

Comment: @shahanahamza I have updated my answer. You should assign `@variable_2` before `@variable_1`

Comment: thats what i am doing.

Comment: @shahanahamza then, what is the issue ? Is there any error ?

Comment: @shahanahamza i have updated the answer. Have a look.